# Getting key value for Hashmap with If condition

Tags: java, if-statement, collections, hashmap

I am storing the key = "name" and value = "state" in a Hashmap.
Now once I get the hashmap with all keys and values
I want to iterate the hashmap and have to check whether the state(value) is running or not
If the state is not running I want to print the name of that server(which is key in hashmap)
Code I am using is

```
for(int z=0; z<=containsAll.size();z++) {
    if(!containsAll.containsValue("Running")) {
        System.out.println(containsAll.keySet());
    }
}
```

Here contains all is the name of my Hashmap. Can someone help me in getting the name for which state is not running

Comment: you could iterate over the EntrySet (you get that with `containsAll.entrySet()`). Then you check the value for the entry and if it fits your criteria you can print the key of the entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (containsAll != null) {
        containsAll.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (v != null && !v.contains("Running")) {
                System.out.println(k);
            }
        });
    }
```

Iterate every key-value pair of the map, and if the value don't contain "Running", print the key.

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse the map using `entrySet()`

```
   Iterator it = containsAll.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        if(!((pair.getValue()).equals("Running")){
              System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" is not running");
        }
        it.remove(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a new class to represent a server and within this class I'd define the state as boolean and the name as string. Furthermore I'd use a list of those Objects to iterate through and do something like this(given, the list is typed List):

```
...
for(MyServerObject mso : containsAll){
    if(mso.isRunning())
        System.out.println(mso.getName());
}
...
```

If this is not possible as you get the Map as is from somewhere else try the following (I'm assuming your Map is typed Map<String,String>):

```
...
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = containsAll.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
    if("Running".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue())
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " is running!");
}
...
```